# Parse XML file into Python object..?

Tags: python, xml

I tried this to do but didn't get how to do 
        this is my xml.file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record name ="Collection Report" id="view_collection_report_tree" model="cl.wastemanager.collection.report">
        <field name="description">Collection Report Tree</field>
        <field name="model">ir.ui.view</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Collection Analysis">
                <field name="hospital_no" type="string"/>
                <field name="partner_id" type="integer"/>
                <field name="district" type="string"/>
                <field name="town" type="string"/>
                <field name="date" type="string"/>
                <field name="cat1_uom_count" type="integer"/>
                <field name="cat1_uom_qty" type="float"/>
                <field name="cat2_uom_count" type="integer"/>
                <field name="cat2_uom_qty" type="float"/>
                <field name="cat3_uom_count" type="integer"/>
                <field name="cat3_uom_qty" type="float"/>
                <field name="cat4_uom_count" type="integer"/>
                <field name="cat4_uom_qty" type="float"/>
                <field name="cat5_uom_count" type="integer"/>
                <field name="cat5_uom_qty" type="float"/>
                <field name="total_uom_count" type="integer"/>
                <field name="total_uom_qty" type="float"/>
                <field name="plant_id" type="integer"/>
                <field name="vehicle_id" type="integer"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

I want to read it into a python object, something like a list of dictionaries. Because the markup is absolutely fixed, I'm tempted to use regex (I'm quite good at using those). However, I thought I'll check if someone knows how to easily avoid regexes here. I don't have much experience with SAX or other parsing, though, but I'm willing to learn.

I'm looking forward to be shown how this is done quickly without regexes in Python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you could look at something like xml2dict https://pypi.org/project/XML2Dict/

Comment: i checked and i tried also but didn't get out , am reading the file but not getting the data

Comment: "how this is done quickly" How _what_ is done quickly? What _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: the problem is in Field, am little confuse on there to get that and get optput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tried from myself using pandas and I am able to get the output correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse("Filename.xml") #enter your filename what you saved in your system

root = tree.getroot()

columns = ["name", "type"]

datatframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

for node in root[0][0][2][0]:

    name = node.get("name")

    type = node.get("type")

    datatframe = datatframe.append(pd.Series([name, type], index = columns), ignore_index = True)

print(datatframe)
```

Myoutput:

```
               name     type
0       hospital_no   string
1        partner_id  integer
2          district   string
3              town   string
4              date   string
5    cat1_uom_count  integer
6      cat1_uom_qty    float
7    cat2_uom_count  integer
8      cat2_uom_qty    float
9    cat3_uom_count  integer
10     cat3_uom_qty    float
11   cat4_uom_count  integer
12     cat4_uom_qty    float
13   cat5_uom_count  integer
14     cat5_uom_qty    float
15  total_uom_count  integer
16    total_uom_qty    float
17         plant_id  integer
18       vehicle_id  integer
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont really state what you want to achieve but below is an example of extract data from the xml, in this case i am extracting the field name and type from the fields inside the tree element.

```py
import xmltodict
with open("test.xml") as xml_file:
    my_xml = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
    for field in my_xml["openerp"]["data"]["record"]["field"][2]["tree"]["field"]:
        print(f"{field['@name']}: {field['@type']}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hospital_no: string
partner_id: integer
district: string
town: string
date: string
cat1_uom_count: integer
cat1_uom_qty: float
cat2_uom_count: integer
cat2_uom_qty: float
cat3_uom_count: integer
cat3_uom_qty: float
cat4_uom_count: integer
cat4_uom_qty: float
cat5_uom_count: integer
cat5_uom_qty: float
total_uom_count: integer
total_uom_qty: float
plant_id: integer
vehicle_id: integer
```